# Gensim Doc2vec model clustering into K-means

Tags: python, k-means, gensim, doc2vec

I'm new to doc2vec and I hope some one of you can help me with this issue.
I've asked a number of people about this issue, but nobody knows the solution.

What I wanto to do is cluster Doc2vec result into k-means. Please see below the code.

```
mbk = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=3, init_size=400, batch_size=300, verbose=1).fit(model_dm.docvecs[range([2000])                                                                                                 
MiniBatchKMeans.predict(mbk,mbk.labels_ )
```

I'm getting this Error.

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-fbc57a13bf4b> in <module>()
      6 
      7 
----> 8 mbk = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=3, init_size=400, batch_size=300, verbose=1).fit(model_dm.docvecs[:2000])
      9 
     10 #model_dm.docvecs.doctag_syn0[2000]

/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/doc2vec.pyc in __getitem__(self, index)
    351             return self.doctag_syn0[self._int_index(index)]
    352 
--> 353         return vstack([self[i] for i in index])
    354 
    355     def __len__(self):

TypeError: 'slice' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to cluster a single document vector (2001th vector to be precise) on this part of your code:

```
.fit(model_dm.docvecs[2000])
```

I assume you want the first 2000 vectors?

**Edit:**

After looking at the gensim documentation couldn't see a way to get a slice of document vectors. But looking at the [source code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/fbe6db0e29636cab4a919e8909df61091ca4c4c5/gensim/models/doc2vec.py#L342) DocvecsArray accepts a single key (int or str) or a list of keys. With that you can get the first 2000 vectors using:

```
.fit(model_dm.docvecs[range(2000)])
```

It doesn't look satisfying so I will fix my answer if I can find another way later.

Also bear in mind these are *not the first* 2000 vectors since gensim seems to store docvecs as a key:value pair and dictionaries are not ordered.

**Second Edit:**

K-means part of the code also needs to be fixed, you are calling `MiniBatchKMeans` class' `predict` function. And give the class instance (mbk) as an argument. You need to call the class instance's (in which case it is mbk) `predict` function if you need to predict anything else. Which I assume you don't.

You can get the assigned labels using the code below.

```
mbk = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=3, init_size=400, batch_size=300, verbose=1).fit(model_dm.docvecs[range(2000])
mbk.labels_
```

Comment: Hi Umutto, thank you for you answhere. I tried it but I'm getting a new error. Please see below.

Comment: @El-moro hmm sorry about that, I've checked the documentation, you are right. Will edit my answer.

Comment: I'm struggling a couple days with this issue. I hope you can help me with it or somebody else, it looks like nobody knows the solution.

Comment: @El-moro try this, it worked for me. Should be ok assuming you did not train your model with explicit tags.

Comment: for me It does't work please see below for the Error.

Comment: @El-moro That error is about K-means, doc2vec works fine. Let me edit my answer for fixing K-means part.